# Marking possible duplicates as distinct

Tags: mysql, linq, duplicates

I have a query for displaying potential duplicates from a list of phonebook entries with the same **firstname**, **lastname**. The user is then able to merge suspected duplicates after inspected further metadata.

What I can't quite work out is how to have a way of marking pairs as being distinct and not duplicates.

I was going to create a table that list pairs that aren't duplicates but I can't find a way to then exclude these from the generated suspected duplicate list.
The SQL for the list is below. I wondered about returning this then running through it in code but still not quite sure and I wondered if anyone has an efficient solution.

```
SELECT p.*, COUNT(DISTINCT p.PersonId) AS num
FROM people p
GROUP BY CONCAT(p.FirstName, ' ', p.LastName)
HAVING num>1
```

I'm doing this in MySQL and C# but the principles should apply to any language.

Comment: Are you looking for linq equivalent to above sql query? If so provide your linq which you have tried out.

Comment: Hi viki888 thanks for asking and sorry that wasn't clear. No I just wondered if I should use LINQ or some other method to exclude pairs marked as not duplicates once the possible duplicates list was created.

Comment: I think this is what he's asking... You have two people in a database (A and B) who have the same name. The system thinks they might be the same person (a duplicate) but the user knows they are different people, so she marks them in some way as being unique. Then person C is added to the database who again has the same name. The system should be able to flag up that person C could be a duplicate of A or B, but also know that A and B are not the same person.

Comment: AFAIK, it's not possible to do that with the columns that you already have. You need to add a column to your table for that. When the admin or moderator looks at a possible duplicate, he needs to mark it as a non duplicate and that needs to be stored in let us call it the `is_distinct` column.

Comment: e4c5 you are a genius thank you - I was thinking I needed to mark pairs as distinct but of course you don't need to - I feel a bit stupid now - trying to be too clever

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to e4c5 this is now answered.

I had become focused on the fact that we were marking pairs as duplicates to be able to identify potential future duplicates.

As e4c5 points out a simple additional column is_distinct will do - then marking the pair of suspected duplicates as true.

For the new list of suspected duplicates I run the SQL as before but then get the list of names that have suspected duplicates and find the records with these name combinations but that aren't marked as is_distinct. Example C# code and MySQL query below:

```
var peoplenames = peoplelist.Select(p=>p.FirstName + " " + p.LastName);
var joinedpeoplenames = string.Join("','", peoplenames);

SELECT p.*
FROM people p
WHERE CONCAT(p.FirstName,' ',p.LastName) IN ('?joinedpeoplenames')
GROUP BY p.PersonId
```